# Can't seem to bust out of a full page iframe - what are the possible intentions?

Tags: javascript, iframe, framebusting

While looking at my Adsense report today I noticed a domain in there that isn't ours.

I've been running "example.com" since 1997. Today I noticed a site in our reports and when I went to it, it has our site in a full page iframe. I'm concerned that it will begin to engage in clickjacking, damage our standing with Google, or damage the name we've built in the news world.

The site that is hijacking us is called "exampleblog.com" and it appears to have been registered earlier today, Dec. 2nd, 2013.

I tried the following code to try and bust out of the frame, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm not sure how old the code is. Are there more modern techniques?

Here's what I tried:

```
if (document.referrer.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?exampleblog\.com(\/|$)/i)) {
top.location.replace(self.location.href);
}
```

Comment: This might be a step in a wrong direction, but I would try to block that url in my .htaccess or something similar. http://www.queness.com/post/5421/17-useful-htaccess-tricks-and-tips

Comment: Content-Security-Policy ::  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JD_Toims on another site for this code:

```
var allowedList = /^(www\.)?(example\.com|site\.com|another-site\.com)$/;
var currentHost = location.hostname;
var allowedHost = currentHost.search(allowedList);

if(top!=self && allowedHost==-1) { top.location.replace(location); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the top window has the right location, to break out of any iframe:

```
if (window.top.location != window.location) {
  window.top.location.replace(window.location.href);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That does work, but I'm looking to allow a very small number of sites (e.g. stumbleupon) to frame. How would I say "bust out out of everything except this list of sites"? Thx.